# How to takes a list of objects of something type and return list of objects of different type

Tags: java, object, localdate, mapper

I have a problem. I want to write a method which as an argument takes a list of objects of type A, some mapper which change this and returns a list of objects of type B
For example:

```
List <LocalDate> date = mapTo (Arrays.asList ("2014-01-01", "2017-05-05"), here
some mapper);
```

How to do this?

Comment: `return list.stream().map(mapper).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: what method in mapper?

Comment: Probably `LocalDate::parse`

Answer (score 1):

No need to write a generic `mapTo`. Java provides one as part of the streams facility. See [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)).

```
List< LocalDate > dates = 
    Stream
    .of( "2014-01-01", "2017-05-05" )
    .map( LocalDate :: parse )
    .toList() 
;
```

If starting with a `List`, make a stream: `List.of( … ).stream().map( … ).toList()`.

Comment: but i want to write generic.. Any idea how do this?